# Proof that $\max_i(d_i^{(n)})/ \sqrt{n}$ tends to $0$ when $\sum_i (d_i^{(n)})^2 / n$ converges

Tags: probability-distributions, sequences-and-series

Let $d_i^{(n)} \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of integer valued sequences such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})^2}{n} = C < \infty
\end{equation}
Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\max_{i\leq n}d_i^{(n)}}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$?

Additionally, is there a way to make true, for example, by tweaking the second moment condition. For example, is it true if instead we ask that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})^{2+\epsilon}}{n} = C < \infty$ for some positive $\epsilon$ and/or also that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})}{n} = D > 0$

For context, I am working on a dynamic for a class of $n$ sized empirical distributions and i want an order of the maximum of my samples. I feel like there should a relatively "obvious" way to prove this but I fail to see the starting point from which the proof should be attacked.

Comment: $d_i^{(n)} := \sqrt{n}\cdot 1_{i=1}$?

Comment: Thank you, very neat counterexample! Still it does not work when we extend the moment condition to $2+\epsilon$ ...

Comment: then the problem becomes obviously true. if some $d_i^{(n)} \ge \delta \sqrt{n}$, then $(d_i^{(n)})^{2+\epsilon} \ge \delta^{2+\epsilon}n^{1+\epsilon/2}$.

Comment: Indeed. At worst, I will require this but i'm not quite satisfied yet. Thanks a lot I have a better idea of what i should do!